# How can I use something like export forwarders with ld.so on Linux?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ld

What options do I have to achieve export forwarding at the linker level from one shared object to another. I'd have full control of the forwarding library and therefore could specify any dependencies as needed.

What I do *not* want is forwarding function calls by implementing a shallow wrapper function for each exported function. Instead I want the dynamic linker to take care of resolving the symbols so that I need not know the prototypes for all the functions of the target library.

Export forwarding the way Windows does it with DLLs is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx) and documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx1zcd3.aspx), for example.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to achieve export forwarding in the first place?

Comment: @EmployedRussian: combining the interface of several shared objects into one.